# Qt: Track mouse position while QDrag is running

Tags: qt, events, window, qml, mouse

I am developing a Qt application with multiple windows and want to implement cross-window drag&drop functionality for some elements in my program.

To do so, I attach an event filter to the to-be-dragged QML elements and listen for the MousePress/MouseMove events to start the drag procedure as follows:

```
QDrag *drag = new QDrag(quickItem);
QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData();
mimeData->setText("Test");
drag->setHotSpot(QPoint(0, 0));
drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
drag->exec();
```

This works fine, but now I would like to show a little tooltip (being a `QWidget`) while dragging, following the mouse cursor and displaying a short text depending on the element the mouse is currently over (similar to the "Copy to ..." or "Move to..." labels appearing when you drag files around in Windows Explorer).

However, while dragging the element, I don't receive any MouseMove events neither on the `QDrag` object nor on the `quickItem` itself, which makes it impossible to track the mouse position. Since the mouse is grabbed during dragging, there should be some event in Qt that frequently reports the mouse position, no matter where on the screen the mouse is.

I am aware of the `QDrag::setPixmap` method, however this won't allow me to change my tooltip text during dragging and has some other limitations I would like to avoid.

Is there some way to listen to mouse move events while `QDrag` is running, without using platform-specific system APIs?

Comment: May be within  `quickItem` a _mousearea_  somewhere ... you get `onMouseXChanged`, `onMouseYChanged` ??

Comment: This would maybe work as long as the cursor is over one of my windows, however I need to get the events anywhere on the screen to make the tooltip follow the mouse, even if the mouse cursor is outside all my windows.

Comment: In QML you can drag outside window .. which is why the cursor coordinates should always be available

Comment: And you said above its one application with multiple windows, in that case i don't problem from qml side

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I don't think that there is way of doing this without using OS libraries nor getting the mouse position every X miliseconds. It looks like a really specific problem that Qt framework does not contemplate. You will need to write your own class to control this using win32 for windows, x11 for linux and the equivalent of Mac.

**If you want to get the mouse position when your window is active and you are dragging something, check this:**

Searching a bit I've found a solution for getting it when your window has the focus using [`QObject::eventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter).

Create a class (for example EventListener) that inherits from `QObject` and overrides `eventFilter` and a method to set this as your qml window (which inherits from `QObject`) event filter with [`installEventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

**eventslistener.h:**

```
#include <QEvent>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDropEvent>

class EventsListener : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    EventsListener(QObject * ptr) : QObject (ptr) {
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void handleEventsOf(QObject *object) {
        if (object)
            object->installEventFilter(this);
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) override {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::DragMove) {
            QDragMoveEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QDragMoveEvent*>(event);

            qDebug() << "Mouse position dragging (x, y): (" << mouseEvent->pos().x() << ", " << mouseEvent->pos().y() << ")";
            return false; //this is must return false or drop event will be handled by this method and drag&drop won't work correctly
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Now we need to access to an instance (singleton in this case) of this class with `qmlRegisterSingletonType`. You may wish to use [`qmlRegisterType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) instead to register this eventlistener as a type (instead of a singleton) and use signals to notify directly qml the mouse position.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "eventlistener.h"

static QObject *eventsListenerInstance(QQmlEngine *qmlEngine, QJSEngine *engine)
{
    return new EventsListener(engine);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterSingletonType<EventsListener>("AppEventListener", 1, 0, "EventsListener", eventsListenerInstance);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import ...
import AppEventListener 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    id: item
    property string display
    property alias dropEnabled: acceptDropCB.checked
    color: dropArea.containsDrag ? "#CFC" : "#EEE"

    Component.onCompleted: EventsListener.handleEventsOf(item)

...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you got my question right: I know how to intercept the events, the problem is: I don't get any mouseMove events during the drag&drop operation. Your solution would give me the events as long as the cursor is over some window of my application, but I need them anywhere, even if the mouse is outside of my application. This should be possible, since grabMouse is executed during the drag&drop.

Comment: Hummm... My bad, I misunderstood your question. So you need the mouse position when it is dragging something and your program does not have the focus, am I right?

Comment: Yes, and I was hoping there was a Qt way of doing it, other than polling the current mouse position at a high frequency. Otherwise I need to resort to  system libraries notifying me of a global mouse movement.

Comment: I don't think that there is way of doing this without using OS libraries nor getting the  mouse position every X miliseconds. It looks like a really specific problem that Qt framework does not contemplate.

Comment: The problem is that QDrag attaches an event filter to the element, which eats all MouseMove events. So even if you attach an own event filter just before the initialization of QDrag, the QDrag event filter will get the events first and prevent further propagation. For now, I am content with only showing the tooltip while the mouse cursor is over one of my windows. I might have to change the Qt source code to fully solve the issue. It would be nice if Qt developers could provide an own API for these events.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I missed the notification. I'm not sure if it's worth to implement it in the Qt Framework itself. Sadly, as I've mentioned you will need to use OS API for each one or use the alternative of checking its position every X miliseconds.